# Symfony2 user manager bundles?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Which are the best **user manager bundles** for Symfony 2 and why?

I only know FOSUserBundle.
Are there other good bundles for managing users?

(like it was sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for Symfony 1)

I need not a final, closed solution, but the pros and contras for someone to be able to choose the best bundle depending on his needs.

Comment: FOSUserBundle is currently the closest thing to the sfGuard family of plugins that symfony 1.x has

Comment: This may be more of an opinion question. I can't imagine how someone could give an "accepted" answer to this.

Comment: if someone writes the pros and contras for the most widely used user bundles relatively comprehensively, then it is accepted az an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, i wrote an UserBundle implementation for my requirements, after i discovered FOSUserBundle and i learned best practices from it.

I think FosUserBundle is a good choice for user manager in Symfony 2. Because

- Actively maintained and supported
- Provides command line commands for creating new user, activating, promoting etc.
- Built-in forms, controllers and views for user related actions.
- Supports Doctrine, Propel, CouchDB and Mongo for persistance.
- Localization, translations
- Optional features like email activation
- Supported by other bundles like Sonata bundles

I never worked with other UserBundle, but i highly recommend to use FOSUserBundle.